# Cambiar la propiedad de las grillas en bootstrap según la orientación del dispositivo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web responsiva con bootstrap y quiero cambiar las propiedades de la clase col-md-12 segun la orientacion del dispositivo.

tengo dos div:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
   //contenido div 1
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
   //contenido div 2
</div>
```

cuando el ancho es mayor a 992 los div estan en linea uno al constado del otro y cuando la resolucion es menor se pone uno debajo del otro por la clase col-md-12 de boostrap, pero quiero que solo se pongan uno debajo del otro cuando el dispositivo tenga una orientacion portrait y cuando sea landscape siga en linea uno al lado de otro.

he intentado esto pero no me funciona.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    /*boortrasp md*******************************/
    .col-md-12 {
       width: 50%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise el código css del archivo de boostrap para ver las propiedades de las clases col-md-12 y col-md-6 y encontre esto.

```
 .col-md-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
.col-md-12 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

así que al final cambie las propiedades de la clase col-md-12 por las de col-md-6 cuando la orientación es landscape y me quedo así:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    /*boortrasp md*******************************/
    .col-md-12 {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 50% !important;
        flex: 0 0 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto te felicito por encontrar y publicar la solución, mi única recomendación sería: por favor cuando te sea posible considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada de modo que los demás identifiquemos que esto es la solución. Saludos